# jenkins access to maven properties and variables

Tags: maven, properties, parameters, jenkins

I've some issue to be resolved - after Jenkins has finished its build, I would like to run a shell script ( Linux OS ) in order to deploy application. I've try to use specific plugin, and came to the conclusion to not to use it and use script instead. So, in my script I need to have some input values which I would like not to be passed manually, but whose values been taken from mavens pom.xml files, or, maybe from settings.xml (maven settings file). Is there a way for that to be done ?

Following is the script being executed:

java -classpath /weblogic/appServer/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar -Xmx256m weblogic.Deployer -adminurl t3://localhost:7301 -username admin -password ProL1antADMIN -upload -deploy -source /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/calendar/workspace/target/futurecrm-stub-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war -targets AdminServer

So, server name, server port, source itself with its path and aftifact name are desired to be substituted with something like $server.name $server.port $source $artifactId $packaging ${project.finalName}

Comment: Couldn't you use maven exec plugin rather than calling java on the command line ?

Comment: Rather than using information from .xml files can you use environment variables? Then you could just add the env to the configuration page of your server.

Comment: Yeap, I did come up with the solution to use maven-exec-plugin instead of post-build script. Been mistaken with the first choice. Thanks a lot guys, for your attention and time !

Answer (score 0):

As @rcomblen recommends, it is a far better to use maven-exec-plugin instead !

P.S.: @better_use_mkstemp - unfortunately, no, this is not allowed in our enviroment